# Data structure to find the m smallest elements in O(N)?

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am trying to write an algorithm to return the smallest 'm' elements in an array, and the return elements have to be in order from smallest to largest.

Given that 1<=m<=sqrt(n) where n is the size of the array.

For example, if the array is {8,1,12,83,33,53} and m is 3, it should return {1,8,12} (in any form).

What's the best common data structure I could use to achieve this in O(N)?

I am thinking to use a Min-heap, but then I can't always get the return elements in order though.

Comment: The question linked as a dupe doesn't say anything about returning the elements in sorted order, but you can sort them in less than O(N) time after you find them.

Comment: `{8,1,12,83,33,53} and m is 3` but `SQRT(6)<2.5`

Answer (score 0):

Since `m < sqrt(n)`, you can get the elements out of the heap in any order and then sort the array. The total complexity of this operation shall be less than `O(N)`

```
(O(MlogM) < O(M^2) < O(N))
```

EDIT:
Building the heap would be an O(NlogM) operation IMO since you have to iterate over the entire array. So if you are considering logM as very small, then this is a feasible solution.

Edit2:
[This link by Jim Mischel](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice) gives more information on this problem solution.

Comment: Building a heap in-place (i.e. rearranging items in an array to form a binary heap) is an O(n) operation. Also, removing the items would be O(m log n), not O(m log m).

Comment: @JimMischel The algorithm that I have in mind is: Build an external max-heap of only m elements by iterating through the array and if any new element is less than the top-most element in the heap then pop out the top-most element and make an insertion for the new element. After building the heap, you have m smallest elements from the array. These can be sorted in MlogM time.

Comment: That algorithm is actually O(n log m) to build the heap because you have to look at every item and potentially (if the list is reverse-sorted) add every item to the heap. Removing the items from the heap is O(m log m), but they'll come out reverse-sorted. Reversing them is O(m). In practice, that algorithm will be faster than Quickselect (which is O(n) in general, O(n^2) in pathological cases) when m is much smaller than n. I studied this in some detail and wrote a longish blog post about it. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/.

Comment: Wow! thanks for link. It is very informative.